# Removing properties from feature in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature in my OpenLayers vector layer.
when I do

```
feature.getProperties()
```

I get object like this

```
{geometry: D, drawnAt: "anygeojson.com", date: "", time: "15:20:16", polu: "vgh"}
```

I want to remove date property from this so that it will look like this

```
{geometry: D, drawnAt: "anygeojson.com", time: "15:20:16", polu: "vgh"}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm using OL 5 actually

Answer (score 1):

```
delete feature.getProperties().date
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

or

```
feature.unset('date');
```

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html#unset

Comment: Yeah, Unset is an option but the thing is. I'm having a front end where User can add or remove properties via a table, that means when they click on save the table, I want to use all those rows as property for my feature. So It can be an object of whole different properties as well.